# Can't link my android apps in play-store

Tags: android, google-play

There is a way enables you to link your apps in the play-store which is explained [**here**](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html)

But unfortunately it became useless or there is a bug in the play-store now so when I press the **"More Apps"** button it doesn't show my apps list as shown But it shows apps of different developers not me.

**Can anyone provide a solution ??**
Thanks in advance :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is working very fine for me:

```
  goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://search?q=pub:PublisherName"));
  startActivity(goToMarket);
```

Comment: I'm using play-store v 5.1.11 
Do you have an older one?

Comment: I'm using 5.1.11 on my Nexus 5. I tested this once again just now and seems to be working. Maybe temporary problem on Google side.